# What is the advantage of using composite primary key instead of single primary key in this context?

Tags: mysql, cakephp, database-design, primary-key, composite-primary-key

Cakephp v3 is now able to support composite primary key. 
http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/quickstart.html

One example given at the quick start guide;

```
CREATE TABLE users (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    email VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    password VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    created DATETIME,
    modified DATETIME
);

CREATE TABLE bookmarks (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    user_id INT NOT NULL,
    title VARCHAR(50),
    description TEXT,
    url TEXT,
    created DATETIME,
    modified DATETIME,
    FOREIGN KEY user_key (user_id) REFERENCES users(id)
);

CREATE TABLE tags (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    title VARCHAR(255),
    created DATETIME,
    modified DATETIME,
    UNIQUE KEY (title)
);

CREATE TABLE bookmarks_tags (
    bookmark_id INT NOT NULL,
    tag_id INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (bookmark_id, tag_id),
    INDEX tag_idx (tag_id, bookmark_id),
    FOREIGN KEY tag_key(tag_id) REFERENCES tags(id),
    FOREIGN KEY bookmark_key(bookmark_id) REFERENCES bookmarks(id)
);
```

The Quick start guide mentions `"You may have noticed that the bookmarks_tags table used a composite primary key. CakePHP supports composite primary keys almost everywhere, **making it easier to build multi-tenanted applications**."`

What is meant by multi-tenanted applications? In this context, why is it better to use composite primary key versus single primary key?

Comment: It is better at some place to use composite primary key not everywhere.
As you can see we do not need any other primary key here and both of the key themselves serve the purpose of primary key if combined, hence it is better to use here a composite primary key.

Comment: *supports composite primary keys almost everywhere, **making it easier to build multi-tenanted applications**.*  The should read *making it **possible** to build a **Relational Database**.*  Tenanted or not. Relational Keys are compound Keys, simple as that.  If you don't have Relational Keys, you don't have a Relational Database, or Relational Integrity, or power, or speed ...  you have a Record Filing System.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In a nutshell: [clustering](http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/clustering/index-organized-clustered-index).

InnoDB will automatically cluster (physically group together) `bookmarks_tags` rows with the same `bookmark_id`, making certain queries<sup>1</sup> extremely fast because DBMS doesn't have to "jump" all over the table to gather all the related rows.

There is no need for a surrogate key (auto-increment int) in this case, nor for the additional price you'd otherwise pay for its underlying index. For more thorough discussion on natural vs. surrogate keys, take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/surrogate-key/info).

While I'm not familiar with Cakephp v3, I would guess that they simply mean that you can prefix the keys of all tables with a tenant ID and pay very little in performance terms due to clustering.

---

<sup>1</sup> Such as: "find tags of given bookmark". And since you also have index on `{tag_id, bookmark_id}`, the opposite query: "find bookmarks of given tag" will also be fast.

Comment: Upvoted. So, in this case, the advantage is faster performance.

Comment: @user768421 It's usually a matter of performance, but may also be necessary for correctness in some cases - see "diamond-shaped dependencies" in the second link. Even in this case, you __have__ to have the composite key to avoid using same tag for same bookmark multiple times. The only question is whether you'll _also_ need a surrogate key - which seems to have answer "no" in this context.

Comment: @user768421 And you seem to be having a good fortune to use a tool that doesn't _force_ you into using surrogate keys, so you can use whatever key design is more appropriate for each particular case.

Comment: That Surrogate Key tag wiki is very confused (a) a surrogate is not a "key", it is just a surrogate (it fails the definition of Key in the *RM, and it does not have any properties of a Key) (b) You need it for basic Relational Integrity, in any hierarchy of tables, not only for "diamond shaped" ones !!! (c) The main advantage of a composite Key is Integrity (d) There is no such thing as "superkey" in the Relational paradigm, it is a fabrication of the detractors.

Comment: @PerformanceDBA (a) Please list the properties of a key and specify which ones are not held by surrogate key. (b) Please (re)read my fist comment above. BTW, how do you define "basic relational integrity"? (c) Not much argument here, except it can depend on the context - sometimes you redesign your keys specifically for performance. (d) Whether you define "relational paradigm" to include it or not, it's still a useful mental tool.

Comment: @Branko Dimitrijevic.  (a) All that can't be answered in comments. Please open a new Question. The *RM* is available online (b) I have written all that up multiple times, just google. (c) Evidently you believe in subjective "truths".  I cherish objective truth.  The former debate.  For the latter, there is no debate to be had.

Comment: @PerformanceDBA I'm agreeing with you on (c), in case you haven't noticed. As for other points, I could say exactly the same thing to you... but that's not a proper way to debate. On top of that, you haven't even defined your terms! I don't know what you mean when you say "RM" or "basic relational integrity" or even "surrogate" (is it different from "surrogate __key__"?)!

Comment: @Branko Dimitrijevic. You are losing me.  You say you are agreeing, but you are doing the opposite.  I repeat, I do not debate, I stand on evidence.  People who debate issues that were closed 30 years ago stand in denial of evidence.  I do not have private definitions, I am quite happy with the Engineering definitions. *RM* means *The Relational Model* by Dr E F Codd, not the rubbish written by other authors.  Perhaps a Chat session.

Comment: @Branko.  From your comment elsewhere, you appear to think that I am *not interested in a discussion*.  **That is incorrect.**  As evidenced in the comments above, I have (a) invited you to open a new Question, in order to answer your questions.  The wiki needs correction, badly. It uses non-relational terms.  (b) Further, after your evidenced confusion, I invited you to Chat, in order to allow a discussion, hopefully leading to closure.  (c) *I do not debate evidenced facts* is an attempt to limit scope of the Chat. (d) We can start with definitions.

Answer (score 3):

**Multi-tenanting** is keeping several different organizations' data in the same database, but in a way that keeps their data logically separate from each other.  This is a common approach for system providers who have many customers using one common application.

The significance of the comment in the CakePHP documentation that you cited is that they expect you to segregate multiple organizations' (tenants') data within a single set of tables by adding something like `org_id` to each table's primary key.

Of course, there are other reasons to use composite primary keys within the context of a single user system too, but obviously CakePHP had multi-tenant support in mind when they added this feature.

Answer (score -1):

if we do `select * from bookmarks_tags` then **Sorting** will be done on the basis of column `bookmarks_id(first field)` of table `bookmarks_tags`.